# Is there a inbuilt function to check if a number is integer in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

Is there an inbuilt is integer function in sml?

I mean something like:

I have to read a number from file and display it as output if it integer and raise exception if the number is not integer. for example I have to check if the output of (Int.fromString()) is integer and display it if it is ...(repeat above)

Comment: What exactly do you want? A function that takes a double and returns true if that double doesn't have a fractional part? Note that that wouldn't be very accurate for large doubles. Or a function that takes an int and always returns true? That wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type system will ensure that the types of the values a function is given match the type signature of the function.

That is, if you have a function that takes an integer as input, such as

```
fun double n = 2 * n
(* this function has type: int -> int *)
```

Then `n` will always be an integer. It will not be possible to call the function with anything but an integer; it will give a type error.

If you have a polymorphic function, such as

```
fun pair n = (n, n)
(* this function has type: 'a -> 'a * 'a *)
```

Then you cannot know what type the input is at runtime. All types of input will be treated the same.

You can, however, always restrict a polymorphic function to only work on a given type, by making the type explicit when defining the function:

```
fun pairInt (n : int) = (n, n)
(* this function has type: int -> int * int *)
```

You can see the difference between `pair` and `pairInt` by comparing what you get from calling `pair 5` to `pairInt 5`, and `pair "foo"` to `pairInt "foo"`.

---

If you have an `int option`, as is the case if you try to convert an `string` to a `int` using `Int.fromString`, you can extract the `int` in several ways. For how to do this, I refer you to the question "[In smlnj how do you convert “string option” to “string”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6268700/79061)".

Comment: I have to read a number from file and display it as output if it integer and raise exception if the number is not integer.
for example I have to check if the output of (Int.fromString()) is integer and display it if it is ...(repeat above).

Comment: @user1710036: I suggest you update your question to reflect this. I've updated my answer.